# Npm remove test folders for production

Tags: node.js, npm

npm prune --production removes packages from devDependencies. Is there any way to it also delete project folders that I do not want in production, such as my "spec" testing folder?

Comment: are you talking about `.npmignore`? If you set it the files listed there will not be published

Comment: It is what I was looking for. Actually, it does solve my problem with npm repositories. It does't download .npmignore folders when npm install is executed. But npm prune --production doesn’t clear .npmignore folders.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune.html), `npm prune` is used to mantain `node_modules` clean of extraneous packages, with the added functionality of removing dev dependencies when switching to production, so no, it doesn't seem configurable to perform such a task.

You could define a custom script in your `package.json` that will delete the folders and invoke `npm prune` after.